# Race conditions in threads despite mutexlocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition

This code calculates the sum of all integers in an array, evenly dividing the work between multiple threads. However every once in a while the thread numbers as well as the localsum of the thread are messed up. I am assuming it's because void* param and globalindex are accessed by multiple threads at the same time. What does not make sense is the fact that it happens, even though I mutexlocked every global variable in this code.
How do I fix this?

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

using namespace std;
int y =0;
int sum=0;
int array[1000000];
int x=0;
int leftoverHandle = 0;
int globalindex = 0;  
int eachThreadHandles =0;

void* add(void* param){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int localindexup = globalindex + eachThreadHandles;
    int localindexdown = globalindex;
    int localsum=0;
    long localparam = (long)param;

    if(y != leftoverHandle ){
            localindexup++;
            y++;

    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


    while(localindexdown<localindexup){

            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            sum = sum+array[localindexdown];
            localsum = localsum+array[localindexdown];
            localindexdown++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


    }




    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    globalindex = localindexdown;
    printf("Thread %ld", localparam);
    printf(": %d\n", localsum);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    if(argc != 3){
            cout<<"Incorrect number of argument";
            exit(1);
    }
    string line;
    string f = argv[1];
    const char *filename = f.c_str();



    int maxthreads = atoi(argv[2]);

    FILE* inFile = fopen(filename,"r");
    int i=0;
    if(inFile == NULL){
    cout<<"fopen failed"<<endl;
    }

    fscanf(inFile, "%d",&i);

    while(!feof(inFile)){

    array[x]=i;
    x +=1;

    fscanf(inFile,"%d",&i);

    }

    fclose(inFile);

    pthread_t id[maxthreads];

    leftoverHandle = x%maxthreads;
    eachThreadHandles = (x - leftoverHandle)/maxthreads;


    for(long i=0; i< maxthreads;i++){
            long status = pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, add, (void*) i);
            if(status){
                    printf("Error creating thread! \n");
                    exit(0);
            }
    }

    for(long i=0; i<maxthreads;i++){
    pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
    }


    cout<<"Sum="<<sum<<endl;




return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not updating `globalindex` right after initializing `localindexup` and `localindexdown` per each thread, i.e in the first critical section.
You have three critical sections in your code.
Imagine that `thread0` runs the first critical section, then `thread1` preempts `thread0` right after `thread0` releases the lock of the first critical section. But because you are setting `globalindex` to `localindexdown` in the third critical section, not the first one, `thread1` will still see `globalindex=0`, just like `thread0`, so it is going to recalculate the same sum as `thread0`. You should put `globalindex = localindexdown;` into the first critical section.
Actually there is no need for the third critical section at all:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int localindexup = globalindex + eachThreadHandles;
    int localindexdown = globalindex;
    int localsum=0;
    long localparam = (long)param;

    if(y != leftoverHandle ){
            localindexup++;
            y++;

    }
    globalindex = localindexdown; //<--- MOVED HERE
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

And forget my comment about the loop, I made a mistake: `while(localindexdown<localindexup)` can be safely preempted because the variables are not shared among threads. You can just improve the performance a bit by reducing the mutexed region to include only shared data:

```
    while(localindexdown<localindexup)
    {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            sum = sum+array[localindexdown];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);     //<--- MOVED HERE
            localsum = localsum+array[localindexdown];
            localindexdown++;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. When I run it multiple times, race condition still occurs. Which is why I am so puzzled by it. Your code puts every single variable into mutex and yet the race condition is still there.

Comment: could you show the code with thread invocations (the ones where you actually use that `add()`)?